# Added Randoop plugin in maven to generate unit tests.. And Stuck with this error

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, randoop

I added Randoop plugin from [GitHub's reference](http://github.com/5aab/randoop-maven-plugin#start-of-content) and Ran the mvn command `mvn clean test`. It failed to generate tests for all of my apps java classes. My application is based on Spring MVC, Java and Hibernate. Will Randoop work with Spring?

JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

```
2018-12-14 01:46:04.807  INFO 10480 --- [           main] .c.q.b.w.r.IndustryBenchmarkResourceTest : Starting IndustryBenchmarkResourceTest on xxxxxxx with PID xxxx (started
by c-xxxxx in D:\Workspaces\Quantix_Deployment_new\xxxxx\xxxxxx)
2018-12-14 01:46:04.807 DEBUG 10480 --- [           main] .c.q.b.w.r.IndustryBenchmarkResourceTest : Running with Spring Boot v1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.4.RELEASE
2018-12-14 01:46:04.808  INFO 10480 --- [           main] .c.q.b.w.r.IndustryBenchmarkResourceTest : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-14 01:46:23.489 ERROR 10480 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:436)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:425)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of context to your question?

Comment: Added Randoop plugin from github's reference https://github.com/5aab/randoop-maven-plugin#start-of-content and Ran the mvn command "mvn clean test" and it failed to generate Tests for all of my apps java classes. My application is based on Spring MVC, java and hibernate. Will Randoop work with Spring ?